# Change of basis of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried to change \begin{pmatrix} a& 0 \\ 0& -a\end{pmatrix} to \begin{pmatrix}0& *\\ *&*\end{pmatrix} To do that, I let $e_1,e_2$ be the standard basis and define $e_1' = e_2$ and $e_2' = e_1$ so that $(a,0) = ae_2'$ and $(0,-a) = -ae_1'$. So I thought after I change the basis, the matrix should be \begin{pmatrix}0 & -a\\ a& 0\end{pmatrix} but the change of basis matrix is \begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix} so
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 &1\\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a& 0\\ 0& -a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 &1\\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-a &0\\ 0& a\end{pmatrix}$$
Something is very wrong in here. Could you help?

Comment: Try the basis $e_1 + e_2, \, e_1 - e_2$.

Comment: @Tychonoff3000 I'm asking why my try fails

Comment: The vectors $e_1'$ and $e_2'$ are still eigenvectors, thus the matrix in this basis will still be diagonal.

Comment: @Tychonoff3000 Why $\begin{pmatrix}0& -a\\ a& 0\end{pmatrix}$ wrong? $(a,0) = ae_2'$ and $(0,-a) = -ae_1'$ so I think the resulting should be that.

Comment: If you call the linear map associated to this matrix $f$, we get the following: $f(e_1') = f(e_2) = -a e_2 = -a e_1'$ and $f(e_2') = f(e_1) = a e_1 = a e_2'$. I think you forgot the last step in these equalities, namely writing the image of the basis vectors $e_1', e_2'$ under $f$ again as a linear combination of the basisvectors $e_1', e_2'$. (You wrote these images in coordinates w.r.t. basis $e_1, e_2$)